# How to calculate expectation of product of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Let $X\sim U(1,n)$ and $Y\sim U(1,n)$ be two discrete random variables that distributes uniformly between $1$ and $n$. (I also have a joint distribution table of $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}(X,Y))$.

I need to find $Cov(X,Y)$.

This is my work so far:
For simplicity, let $E(X)=\mu _x$, and $E(Y)=\mu _y$.
So, by definition:

$Cov(X,Y)=E[(X-\mu_x)(Y-\mu_y)]=E[XY-X\mu_y-Y\mu_x+\mu_x\mu_y]=$
$E(XY)-\mu_x\mu_y-\mu_x\mu_y+\mu_x\mu_y=E(XY)-\mu_x\mu_y$

and then: 
$\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}x_iy_j\mathbb{P(X=x_i,Y=y_j)}-\mu_x\mu_y$

But how can I calculate this sum?
I'm not so sure about it, but do I sum **every** single value in the joint distribution table and multiply it by it's corresponding probability?

Comment: In principle: yes. If you know certain things (p.e. $X$ and $Y$ are independent) then it can become more easy.

Comment: Use the joint table to calculate $E(XY)$ as described.  If this table reveals that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, you are done, if not, just calculate.

Comment: Thank you both for the help!
Why is it easy when I know they're independent?

Comment: Independency implies that the covariance equals zero. Calculating by means of the table will give you $\mathbb{E}XY=\mu_{x}\mu_{y}$.